# convert date format from dd.mm.yy hh:mi:ss to yyyy-mm-dd in Hive

Tags: hive

I am receiving date format in the format dd.mm.yy hh:mi:ss and i need to convert it into yyyy-mm-dd , no issues if it is a string.

example:14.02.2017 18:00:00
result needed : 2017-02-14

i need it in Hive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('14.02.2017 18:00:00','dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss'),'yyyy-MM-dd');
OK
2017-02-14
```

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

Comment: Please leave an explanation of your code so others can learn and understand. Thanks!